# How to format large USB external drive to FAT32 for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, backup, usb-drive, fat32

I am trying to help a friend back up some files to an external USB drive from a machine running Ubuntu.  The drive is a 1.36 TB big and is using NTFS.  From what I can tell I need to reformat it to FAT32.  But FAT32 does not seem to be able handle a drive that big.

I tried `mkfs -t vfat` but it still shows as NTFS on the Ubuntu machine.  Which is funny because when I plug it into my Windows 7 machine to format it there it shows up as FAT32.  I also tried SwissKnife but it only offered me FAT16 - I want FAT32.

What can I do?

Comment: So if you are going to down vote at least say why - how else am I going to know what to do different next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you manually re-mount the drive as vfat?

```
umount /MOUNTPOINT
mount -t vfat -v /dev/sdXX /MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: Don't know - will try it tonight and get back to you :)